# EF pre-generate view. How to be sure that these views are using by EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have several performance issue in my website.
I'm using asp.net mvc 2 and Entity Framework 4.0. I bought a Entity Framework Profiler to see what kind of SQL request that EF generated.

By example, some page take between 3 and 5 seconds to open. This is to much for my client. 
To see if it's a performance  problem with  SQL generated by EF, I used my profiler and Copy / Paste the generated SQL in Sql Management Studio to see the execution plan and the sql statistic. The result show in less than a second. 

Now that I eliminated the SQL query, I suspect EF at buidling query step. 
I Follow the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896240.aspx)  step by step to pre-generate my view. I didn't see any performance gain. 
**How to be sure that my query use these Pre-Generated Views ?** 
Is there anything I can do to increase performance of my website ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that the pre-compiled queries still take just as long (in fact a little longer) the first time they are run, because the queries are compiled the first time they are invoked. After the first invocation, you should see a significant performance increase on the individual queries.

However, you will find the best answer to all performance questions is: figure out what's taking the most time first, then work on improving in that area. Until you have run a profiler and know where your system is blocking, any time you spend trying to speed things up is likely to be wasted.

Once you've determined what's taking the most time, there are a lot of possible techniques to use to speed things up:

1. Caching data that doesn't change often
2. Restructuring your data accesses so you pull the data you need in fewer round trips.
3. Ensuring you're not pulling more data than you need when you do your database queries.
4. Buying better hardware.
5. ... and many others

One last note: In Entity Framework 5, they plan to implement automatic query caching, which will make precompiling queries practically useless. So I'd only recommend doing it where you know for sure that you'll get a significant improvement.